# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED using google cloud api with Python

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have been trying to resolve this annoying issue with google cloud api (specifically I'm trying to use vision API) using Python 2.7.12 on windows 7.
This is the very simple code I'm running:

```
from google.cloud import vision
vision_client = vision.Client()
image_one = vision_client.image(source_uri='gs://MY_BUCKET/MY_PHOTO.jpg')
labels = image_one.detect_labels(limit=5)
```

But this ends up with:

```
E0527 16:50:58.714000000 10868 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.c:937] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
```

After reading endless suggested solutions - I have added an environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE linked to a certificate downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. This only resolved this issue for a couple of hours but then the above-mentioned failure returned.

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong and what are the exact steps so to have this resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you are doing, it's just that the certificate of what you are connecting to is not trusted. It can be either a certificate itself or the issuing authority. In your case I think it is the latter.

Your environment variable must have been invalidated when opening a new session. See this thread for where to put your certificates bundle: https://superuser.com/questions/442793/why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows

Comment: I'm not using curl and adding the CURL_CA_BUNDLE environment variable, as instructed in the above link, did not help.
Are there any concrete steps to do to get google cloud api work with Python 2.7.12?